# Algebra parameter

Tags: linear-algebra

$x,y,z,u$ are variables and $a,b$ parameters

$(a+1)y+x−(a+1)z−au=1$

$(a−1)x+(2a+1)z+(a−2)u=1$

$(−a−2)z+(a+2)u=b−2$

Now, next steps are these:

If $a\neq−1,a\neq1,a\neq−2$: System is indefinite

If $a=−1$: System is indefinite

If $a=1$: System is indefinite

If $a=−2$: System can be either indefinite or impossible

My question is how did we got that first part where $a$ can't be $1,−1$ or $−2$. Why it can be $2$ or $0$ or some other number?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If we plugg $$x=1-(a+1)y+au+(a+1)z$$ into the second equation we get
$$y(1-a^2)+u(a^2-2)+z(a^2+2a)=2-a$$